# Getting Keys Using Unique Values in Dictionary

Tags: python

I have a code like this.When i'm executing this it prints only 'hello' but i want both. I want to print both keys in my dictionary because i'm passing here unique value can any one help me.

```
mydict = {'hai': 35, 'hello': 35}
print mydict.keys()[mydict.values().index(35)]
```

Comment: Ideally you should look for keys and get values. this is why you use `dict`

Answer (score 5):

`index()` only returns the first match by design. The best solution is probably a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> keys = [key for key,value in mydict.iteritems() if value==35]
>>> keys
['hello', 'hai']
```

Comment: +1 This is likely to be simplest way.   For multiple lookups, the fastest way is to create a reverse lookup dictionary:  ``{35: ['hai', 'hello'], 50: ['bye', 'c-ya']}``.

Answer (score 0):

```
mydict = {'hai':35,'hello':35}
a=[]
for k, v in mydict.iteritems():
    if v == 35:
        a.append(k)

print a
```